setting state through context is not re-rendering page
I'm trying to learn TypeScript.  I'm able to do a simple useState hook on a simple page.  However when I want to be able to set state using context I can't get it to set the state properly as is shown by its inability to re-render on the page.
App.tsx

export interface User {
  isSubscribed: boolean;
  name: string;


}


const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({
    isSubscribed: true,
    name: 'You',
  })

  return(


  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <DashboardContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        </DashboardContext.Provider>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
)
};

export default App;

context.tsx:
export interface DashboardInterface {
    user: User
    setUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<User>>
}

export const DashboardContext = createContext<DashboardInterface>(undefined);


export function useUserContext() {
    const {user, setUser} = useContext(DashboardContext)
    if (user===undefined){
        throw new Error("useUserContext must be used with a Dashboard Context")
    }
    return {user, setUser}
}

Home.tsx
const Home: React.FC = () => {

  interface Thing {
    title: string;
    nickname: string
  }

  const {user, setUser }= useUserContext()
  const [thing, setThing]=useState<Thing>({
    title: "Mr",
    nickname: "Morale",
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in the useEffect")

  },[user])

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>User {user.name} {thing.nickname}</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">Blank</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        
        <IonButton onClick={()=>{setUser({isSubscribed: false, name: "Pete"}); console.log('clicked!', user); setThing({title: "Mrs", nickname:"Morales"})}}>
          Change Name
        </IonButton>
        
        <ExploreContainer />
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;

Here in Home.tsx I have a button that when I push it I expect it to change the user.name to "Pete" and the Thing.nickname to "Morales" as can be displayed in the  component.
when I click the button.  Only thing.nickname changes from Morale to Morales.  (Thing is something I set up all on the Home.tsx page).  However user.name stays the same as "You" (user is something I set up on App.tsx and context.tsx.)  Therefore, I think I am doing something wrong with using context.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

The react context should work, see example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-5u43j1?file=src%2FHome.tsx , you need to debug your code

Try something like the code below to observe your user variable. It will run when the user value is changed. If the logged user variable is updated, then you might want to look at your rendering.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
      
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('user:', user);
}, [user]);

If the user doesn't change, try removing the context and using useState within the Home component to see if the state updates as expected. This removal can help isolate whether the issue is in the context setup or with the state update logic.

I did that and it logs out no changes (user always has a name variable of "You")

useState's async nature can cause a problem. Try using the code below to give React some time to update the user variable.
setTimeout(() => {
console.log('updated user:', user);
}, 1000);
Also, try removing the context and useState within the Home component

Tried the Timeout still no change.  I'm not sure what you mean by remove the context and useState out of there.

I meant to try removing the DashboardContext.Provider and use (user, setUser) in App.tsx to see if it's working there.

Well I removed all context and moved the user, setUser to Home.tsx and it works perfectly fine so it is definitely a context thing I have to figure out.

I just had to move my provider outside !

Me too! Being inside the office wasnt working....
